# Variables in commands on the commandline

Tags: windows, python-2.7, openssh

I'm using Python 2.7 and Paramiko module 2.1.2 to automate some tasks against  Windows servers running OpenSSH (no full Cygwin install).   I have working code, but I'm trying to enhance it.  (Hopefully, I did not break it when I anonymized it.)

What I'm trying to do is enhance the code such that I can replace parts of the  "stdin.write" lines with variables.  For my *Nix hosts, I just did something like this:

```
my_linux_var = "/FooBar/barFoo/log"
my_linux_cmds = "cd " + my_linux_var + "\n" + \
                "more instructions, blah, blah" + "\n"
stdin.write(my_linux_cmds)
```

Although it's ugly, it works.   However, the same technique does not work for my Windows hosts.  Sending commands in the above manner puts me in in a shell.  I can navigate by changing the backslashes to slashes, but I have not figure out a way around the Windows variables.  Although I don't get errors, the shell does not appear to assign or perhaps retrieve variables.  For example,

Pub1="True"
echo %Publ%

results in "%Pub1%" being echoed.  What are some possible solutions to my problem, and it there a better way to go about this in a *Nix environment?

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("10.9.8.7", username="user", password="passwd")
channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
stdout = channel.makefile('rb')
stdin.write('''
E:
cd E:\Foo\bar\log
for /f %c in ('E:\Foo\bar\bin\somecmd -readparams /LogManagement/EnablePublish1') do set Pub1=%c
if exist %COMPUTERNAME%_Bar_Log1.txt echo y|del %COMPUTERNAME%_Bar_Log1.txt
echo.%Pub1%|findstr /C:"1" >nul
if not %ERRORLEVEL% 1 (
    type Bar_Log1.*txt >> %COMPUTERNAME%_Bar_Log1.txt
}
for /f %c in ('E:\Foo\bar\bin\somecmd -readparams /LogManagement/EnablePublish1') do set Pub2=%c
if exist %COMPUTERNAME%_Bar_Log2.txt echo y|del %COMPUTERNAME%_Bar_Log2.txt
echo.%Pub2%|findstr /C:"1" >nul
if not %ERRORLEVEL% 1 (
type Bar_Log2.*txt >> %COMPUTERNAME%_Bar_Log2.txt
)
exit
''')
stdout.close()
stdin.close()
ssh.close()
ssh.close()
```